# Junit5 select directory doesn't find any tests

Tags: junit5

Junit5 doesn't discover test within a folder with --select-directory; I tried to run with junit5 with stand alone runner the following command  java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar -d directory ;

Unfortunately, it seeems that Junit launcher doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdygV.png)

Did Junit5 support select-directory?

Answer (score 0):

`—-select-directoy` is for engines that use file-based (as opposed to code-based) test descriptions, eg Cucumber. If you’re working with code-based tests (eg Jupiter or jqwik) you need to use `—-select-package` instead.